# Regex: add exception (exact match) to existing regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex: `(.+?)(?:index\.html?|\.html?)(.*)?$`

This is used (case-insensitive) to trigger redirects for all URLs which contain "index.html" or ".html". This part is removed by triggering a redirect with the two matching groups and leaving out the middle part (which is either "index.html" or ".html").

Example input URL: https://www.example.com/somePath/subPath/index.Html?someQueryString

This will be redirected to: https://www.example.com/somePath/subPath/?someQueryString

This is all working as expected, but now I want to add an exception to this regex.
The exception is that this redirect should not be triggered if a certain word exists in the first group.

Let's say this word is "safePath".
The following URL should not trigger a redirect, because it contains the word "safePath" in the first group:
https://www.example.com/safePath/subPath/index.Html?someQueryString

How can I change my regex expression to honor this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, though it returns three capturing groups instead of two (it splits the first part of the link into two groups):

```
(https://www.example.com/)(?!safePath/)(.+?)(?:index\.html?|\.html?)(.*)?$
```

(Note: This only matches if `safePath` is the first group in the link as specified in the question. So a link like `https://www.example.com/somePath/safePath/index.html?someQueryString` will still match because `safePath` is in the second group.)

[Test code in Python](https://tio.run/##pdDNCoJAEADgu08xSQctWQ9dQghfoehYEVuNKbg/zI5o0LvbZj90qUun2fnhY2bthUujZ3NLfV8pa4iBMLCSGUnDAiiMSmbrsjRt21ZgJ5WtURyNSuMoHzlZ4FJy6RMxzX0lq/QJu60oWdX59Rl9cxLn4zBgdLx3TJU@O49vwm@2M@rhuuYwxIF9aPfeqkG6rAcoTOA781rvT@a9zcv74eyCwhDcL4VKw@fFWQBg/YsjQlF4QtZ19PzqZJiM476/AQ)

EDIT: I think this should detect whether `safePath` is anywhere in the URL:

```
^(?!.*/safePath/)(.+?)(?:index\.html?l\.html?)(.*)?$
```

Comment: Thanks Aiden, this is a good step in the right direction. Ideally, though, I would want to match on the word anywhere in the URL and I also would like to avoid having the domain name in the URL. (I'm sorry, I know these requirements don't make it easier :))

Comment: @PeterM. Ok yea that make it much harder, I was thinking of something like what Tom Lord was doing but it doesn't seem to work as anticipated.

Comment: @PeterM. I think I have solved the issue, please check my edited post.

Comment: Doesn't work for `https://www.example.com/somePath-123/index.html?someQueryString`

Answer (score 0):

> The following URL should not trigger a redirect, because it contains the word "safePath" in the first group: https://www.example.com/safePath/subPath/index.Html?someQueryString

On way you can probably do this with a [**negative lookahead**](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php) in the regex:

```
(?!.*safepath)(.+?)(?:index\.html?|\.html?)(.*)?$
   ^^^^^^
```

...Or, *potentially*, you could make this a separate conditional - i.e. something like:

```
if(url.contains?('safepath')) {
  return false;
}
```

(This is only intended as pseudo-code, since you didn't specify a language/tools being used.)

Comment: Huh, I tested this and it didn't seem to work? [code in python](https://tio.run/##jdC9CsJADAfwvU8Ri8OdluvgIgW5V1AcVaRqagu9D3KRVvDd61kdXASnhCT8@BN/59rZxdLTMDTGO2IgTHzJjGRhBZQKPVGzUFYYh7UUaq6l0EVjL9jvVc2m1Y9PjcuZ1NM0YQx8DEyNvYZo7NKa2Yciz7uuU9iXxreozs7kwRlcRzYPt9NYR/atvXabG9J9O0JpBr@ZmO5f5pBUjuCVEBoL30mLBMDHjgWhqiJRtq34fCIbL6Uchic)

Comment: Thanks Tom. I didn't provide the programming language, because we're trying to solve it by only changing the regex. (If that's possible, that's far easier in the bigger context.)
I tried your example, but it still seems to match despite the negative lookahead.

Comment: @AidenChow @PeterM. the original question said: **"This is used (case-insensitive)"**. I wrote `safepath` in lower-case, because if the regex is used **case-insensitive** then it's irrelevant how I capitalise the letters. By contrast, your python code is case-sensitive, and is comparing `safepath` to `safePath`.

Comment: @TomLord yeah but that still doesn’t fix the issue that your regex still matches for URLs that contain `safepath`.

Comment: Additionally, that python code doesn't work "as you expect" because it's missing a `^` (start-of-string) from the regex. But again, given the context of OP's question (it's not using `findall`!), I couldn't say for sure if such an addition is actually needed.

Comment: @AidenChow No, it doesn't. Because your python code is using `findall` and isn't matching a *whole string* (i.e. anchored by both `^` and `$`). -- So it could match `afePath....` instead of `safePath...`

Comment: @TomLord well I’m just copy pasting the exact regex you provided in your post, which in fact does not have the `^` anchor.

Comment: @AidenChow OP didn't mention Python or `findall`. You're rejecting my answer due to a mis-usage of a valid solution. Notice how your solution is actually now identical to mine (except for the not-necessarily-correct assumption that `safePath` must be immediately proceeded and followed by forward slash characters?)

Comment: @PeterM. *"I didn't provide the programming language, because we're trying to solve it by only changing the regex"* -- **always** mention the language, if there's the slimmest chance of it being relevant. The exact implementation/behaviour/features of regex vary between languages! As shown from the above exchange, this trivial detail of adding an explicit "whole-string match", and "case-insensitive match" has caused easily-avoidable confusion!

Comment: @TomLord I see what you mean. We are using C#, but for testing some things myself I'm using regex101.com with only the "insensitive" flag.

Comment: @PeterM. Then provide a link to regex101, with a list of inputs you expect to match/not match -- thus eliminating all ambiguity around whether a given solution solves the problem :)